# How to Make a Basic Snippet of Javascript Work in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I found a snippet of Javascript online... that does exactly what I need to solve a problem. BUT I have not been able to get it to work without errors on Worpress.

The snippet is from here: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/remove-anchor-links/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Original JavaScript code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
// Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

  document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(current) {
    if(!current.hash) return;
    if(current.origin + current.pathname != self.location.href) return;
    (function(anchorPoint) {
      if(anchorPoint) {
        current.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          anchorPoint.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
          e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
      }
    })(document.querySelector(current.hash));
  });

</script>
```

I have this set up as it's own .js file in the functions.php (and then am enqeueing it via functions.php). It works (perfectly)... but it breaks other functionality.

Any help here would be GREATLY appreciated!

K

Comment: Hello there KyBo, please do NOT include a link to the snippet, instead add the code in the question.

Comment: there you go XT_Xaos

Comment: You mention you're getting "errors." What errors specifically? It's a little difficult for us to help if we can't reproduce the issue. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what kind of info you should be including in your questions so others can help.

Comment: the reason that I did not include that information is because I have no idea what I am doing. I uploaded the plugin is a way that is very very likely incorrect... hence I did not want to provide errors on an incorrect installation. Further, they were different every time... because I kept trying different ways to instal

Comment: to answer your question, one time I saw a console error "you had a character < where it should not be". another time, I saw a console error "Jquery is not defined". another time, I saw a console error "you are not a developer, you have no business doing what you're doing (jk)."